# returning square of number if odd and (number-1) square if even

Tags: python

```
def odd_square(number):
    if number == 0:
        return 0
    elif number % 2 == 1:
        return number*number
    else:
        return (number - 1)*(number - 1)

square = odd_square(int(input("Enter number to square: ")))
print("square is: ",square)
```

The output should be something like with an input of 7 the function should return 49 and with an input of 6 the function should return 25. But there is an EOF line error. Python version 3.8.0

error:

Enter number to square:

***Error***

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "**tester**.python3", line 9, in

square = odd_square(int(input("Enter number to square: ")))

EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: Cannot reproduce the EOF error

Comment: Please include the error message.  Also, the code included in the question does not cause an error on my computer. Make sure to double check your syntax

Comment: Its seems to work for me, maybe you have indentation error somewhere?

Comment: This could happen if you enter some invalid expression (apparently, you entered nothing when you should have entered a number) while running this code with Python 2. Check the version of Python that you are really running

Comment: It runs for me.  I don't see a visible problem. It's probably a whitespace problem.

Comment: This error occurs when a number is not input on the prompt

Comment: @user1558604 that wouldnt cause EOF error, it would cause valueError as None cannot be converted to int

Comment: @ChrisDoyle, I just tested it. The code works fine with numbers input, when you just click enter though, it gives an EOF error.

Comment: In which version of python did you test it as input accepts empty input this would then be passed to int which would raise valueError

Comment: @ChrisDoyle, that is version 2.7. Just realized the difference between 2.7 and 3 with input vs raw_input. However, given that is the error OP is getting, I am guessing that is the cause.

Comment: @user1558604 yeah your right, it will raise EOF in 2.7 if your not using `raw_input` you should post this as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Python 2.7, `input` will try to execute code in your string input.  Thus, if you don't input anything you will receive and `EOF` error.

In order to prevent execution of random code input by the user, it is recommended to use `raw_input` for Python 2.7. (Or upgrade to Python 3+ and use `input` since support is going away for Python 2.7 in a few weeks).

Even with this change, you will still receive an error from the code if you don't put in any input, it just won't be an `EOF` error.

*Thanks to Chris Doyle for the discussion in the comments*